# Unexpected token: { error

Tags: apex, developer-console

I am trying to write to simple apex but it is giving me Unexpected token:{ error.  this is the first time apex class is being executed in my developer org. I am getting similar error for any class I have written.

I opened this anonymous execution mode in developer console - tried this one from trailhead.

```
List<Vehicle__c> v={SELECT Id, Name from Vehicle__c where Name='X'};
v[0].Name ='Y';
upsert v;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your query. In query we don't use curly brackets. Curly brackets are used in method body declareation.

```
List<Vehicle__c> v=[SELECT Id, Name from Vehicle__c where Name='X']; 
v[0].Name ='Y'; 
upsert v;
```

But In this you might get list index out of bound exception. So you should check list size before using it something like.

```
List<Vehicle__c> v=[SELECT Id, Name from Vehicle__c where Name='X']; 
if(v.size() > 0)
{
    v[0].Name ='Y'; 
    upsert v;

}
```

Comment: Except, this code would only update the first record in the list, which is also probably not what you want.